# What happens when opeator= returns void rather than T&?

Tags: c++, void, return-type, assignment-operator

In operator overloading, the assignment operator is normally defined as follows:

```
T& T::operator =(const T2& b);
```

which returns `T&` as result. But I want to know what happens when we return `void`. For example, the assignment operator of `std::atmoic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` returns `void`:

```
void operator=( std::shared_ptr<T> desired ) noexcept;
```

as defined [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2) and [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.atomic.shared). What happens in this case? Is it ok to always implement the assignment operator like this? I guess this prevents assignments like `a=b=c;` which is good sometimes, isn't it?

Comment: Assignment is just like any other binary expression, and can thus be nested in other expressions. It might not be common outside of chained assignments, but still allowed. By returning `void` you break the standard semantics of the assignment operator.

Comment: *"which is good sometimes, isn't it?"* - I can't say I ever use `a=b=c;`, it's just not as nice as doing the assignments separately IMHO.

Comment: Note that `std::atomic` is non-copyable and non-movable, so chaining of assignments doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Nick I meant preventing such assignments is good sometimes.... :D

Comment: @DanielLangr do you think is it a good practice to return `void` when class is not copyable, at least?

Comment: @Afshin I think there is no generic answer, i.e., no best option. Returning a reference is more idiomatic and, therefore, expected by others. OTOH, it may generate some overhead (such as the additional instruction in this live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/zbx17de5o). However, if the definition is in the same translation unit, this overhead will be likely optimized away once the retuned value is not used.

Comment: If a class is not assignable, it is preferable to `delete` its assignment operator (C++11 and later) rather than  worrying about its return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to chain assignments

```cpp
a = b = c;
```

(Nor introduce more complicated cases, like `(a = b).method();` or `if((a = b));`.)

OTOH, with void return type you don't need the ubiquitous `return *this;` boilerplate.